# Lifetime Problem: "types have different lifetimes, but data from 'self' flows into..."

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have this code:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub struct HitRecord<'a> {
    pub t: f32,
    pub p: Vector3<f32>,
    pub normal: Vector3<f32>,
    pub material: Option<&'a Material>,
}

pub struct Sphere<T>
where
    T: Material,
{
    pub center: Vector3<f32>,
    pub radius: f32,
    pub material: T,
}

impl<T> Sphere<T> {
    fn hit<'a, 'b>(&'a self, ray: &Ray, t_min: f32, t_max: f32, record: &'b mut HitRecord) -> bool
    where
        'a: 'b,
    {
        record.material = Some(&self.material);
    }
}
```

I understand that `record` must have a shorter lifetime than `self`, so I assigned different lifetimes to them and set `'a` to enclose `'b`. But I'm still getting this:

```
error[E0623]: lifetime mismatch
  --> src\tracer\sphere.rs:54:35
   |
30 |     fn hit<'a, 'b>(&'a self, ray:&Ray, t_min:f32, t_max:f32, record:&'b mut HitRecord) -> bool where 'a: 'b {
   |                    --------                                                 ---------
   |                    |
   |                    these two types are declared with different lifetimes...
...
54 |                 record.material = Some(&self.material);
   |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ...but data from `self` flows into `record` here
```

I have beeem fighting this lifetime problem for quite a few hours now and I don't understand what's going on here; what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How does `HitRecord` look like? I'm missing a lifetime parameter here as it seems to contain references, e.g. `HitRecord<'a>`. In general, a more complete example could help us to help you.

Comment: @darkwisebear that's exactly what was missing, thank you! :)

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. Specifically, `Vector3`; `Material`; and `Ray` are missing. Ideally, **remove** the need for them or provide them. Try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here.

Answer (score 4):

The lifetime of the reference inside `HitRecord` has to be set to the same (or less) as the lifetime of &self so that the reference from `record` to self is correct. You don't even have to explicitly set up a relation between 'a and 'b because it's not the lifetime of `record` itself that matters but the lifetime of the struct member `material`. This signature should work:

```rust
fn hit<'a>(&'a self, ray:&Ray, t_min:f32, t_max:f32, record:&mut HitRecord<'a>) -> bool
```

**Edit**: One thing I've seen that you might not be aware of is that you're creating a trait object, i.e. something that enables dynamic dispatch. If you don't need that, you might want to change the declaration of `HitRecord` to

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub struct HitRecord<'a, T: Material> {
    pub t: f32,
    pub p: Vector3<f32>,
    pub normal: Vector3<f32>,
    pub material: Option<&'a T>
}
```

This way, you fix the struct to a certain, statically known type implementing `Material` which enables static, compile time dispatch.